# Codeigniter router get parameter

Tags: codeigniter, parameters, continuous-integration, router

I use $.getJSON() to retrieve some data for a couple of cascading dropdowns in my form. $.getJSON() automatically appends the parameter at the end of the URL like domain.com/controller/method/?parent=5

So, I've declared my method like public function method($parent) which works file, but the same method will be used from other parts of the website that will call it like domain.com/controller/method/5

I tried to create a route in routes.php like the one below:

$route['business/regions/?parent=(:num)'] = 'business/regions/$1';

but it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong? Maybe ? is confusing the regex parser of the router? Do I have to escape it somehow to make it a 'literal' ?  ?

Or is it that router is not used to 'rewrite' get parameters at all? I'm very confused, as it should work but it doesn't and I'm wondering what's wrong with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter route parameters are for url parameters. It is particularly useful when trying to create a REST styled url pattern.

What you're trying to do is get url query string from the url which is not supported via the Codeigniter router. For you to get what you want you can do the following:

In your routes.php:

```
$route['business/regions'] = 'business/regions';
```

and in your controller Business.php:

```
public function regions() {
  //the numeric id you're looking for
  $parent = $this->input->get('parent');
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's almost what I did. What I exactly did was to declare the get parameter as an incoming variable to my method, like public function regions( $parent ), which is a native behavior by the framework anyway.

But I had the impression I can route the parameters as well. That was my mistake. Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: No problem. If this solved your question, mark this as the correct answer! :)

Comment: I clicked the Tick icon and it turned green, that's what you meant, right?